# Share on social media created listing after submission

Tags: plugins, customization, permalinks

I know there are numerous plugins for sharing a custom post types on social media, but what I want to achieve is to offer social share buttons after job has been submitted.

Here is a template that is being shown after job is successfully submitted, I would like to include share buttons within this template (and that those share buttons automatically pull published post permalink):

```
<?php
global $wp_post_types;

switch ( $job->post_status ) :
    case 'publish' :
        echo '<p>';
        printf( __( '%s You listing was successfully published. You can <a href="%s">view you listing/a>. ', 'wp-job-manager' ), $wp_post_types['job_listing']->labels->singular_name, get_permalink( $job->ID ) );
        echo '</p>';
```

Is this achievable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this might be to use a plugin that includes a shortcode (say, Jetpack), and then include that shortcode in the output within `case 'publish'`.